# Error on referencing RadioButton in MainActivity from another class

Tags: java, android, radio-button, stack-overflow, cross-reference

I created an application that will print out the time in binary.
The logic works nicely, but when I tried separating the logic and the GUI I ran into some problems. There seems to be a cross-reference problem but I can't seem to find it.

MainActivity:

```
package se.macke.binarycounter;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    public TextView text0, text;
    public Timer timer;
    public RadioButton rB00,rB01,rB02,rB03, rB04, rB05, rB06, rB07, rB08, rB09, 
                    rB0A, rB0B, rB0C, rB0D, rB0E, rB0F, rB11, rB12;
RadioButton[] rButtons = new RadioButton[18];

public Executive exec = new Executive(); // This is row 25 in the logcat reference
public GregorianCalendar gregCal = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
```

The logic class:

```
/**
 * 
 */
 package se.macke.binarycounter;

import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import android.widget.RadioButton;

/**
 * @author macke
  *
 */
public class Executive
{
//Converts the numbers to a long string with new rows
RadioButton[] rButtons = new RadioButton[18];
GregorianCalendar gregCal = new GregorianCalendar();
MainActivity m = new MainActivity(); // This is row 21 in the LogCat reference

private int sec = gregCal.get(GregorianCalendar.SECOND);                        // time units
private int min = gregCal.get(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE);
private int hour = gregCal.get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR);
```

An excerpt of the logcat:

```
08-25 13:43:53.459: E/AndroidRuntime(383): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 13:43:53.459: E/AndroidRuntime(383): java.lang.StackOverflowError
08-25 13:43:53.459: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(Arrays.java:405)
08-25 13:43:53.459: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.util.ZoneInfo.getOffset(ZoneInfo.java:168)
08-25 13:43:53.459: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.util.ZoneInfo.getOffset(ZoneInfo.java:162)
08-25 13:43:53.459: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at java.util.GregorianCalendar.fullFieldsCalc(GregorianCalendar.java:495)
08-25 13:43:53.459: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(GregorianCalendar.java:658)
08-25 13:43:53.459: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at java.util.Calendar.complete(Calendar.java:839)
08-25 13:43:53.459: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at java.util.Calendar.setTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1339)
08-25 13:43:53.459: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at java.util.GregorianCalendar.<init>(GregorianCalendar.java:339)
08-25 13:43:53.459: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at java.util.GregorianCalendar.<init>(GregorianCalendar.java:239)
08-25 13:43:53.459: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at se.macke.binarycounter.Executive.<init>(Executive.java:20)
08-25 13:43:53.459: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at se.macke.binarycounter.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:25)
08-25 13:43:53.459: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at se.macke.binarycounter.Executive.<init>(Executive.java:21)
08-25 13:43:53.459: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at se.macke.binarycounter.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:25)
08-25 13:43:53.459: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at se.macke.binarycounter.Executive.<init>(Executive.java:21)
08-25 13:43:53.459: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at se.macke.binarycounter.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:25)
08-25 13:43:53.459: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at se.macke.binarycounter.Executive.<init>(Executive.java:21)
```

I understand that the logic shouldn't be aware of the GUI if i can be avoided. Should I initialize the buttons in the logic class instead and in that case, how?

Comment: You really should refine this question. Presenting several hundred lines of code and expecting someone to debug all of them is very unlikely to get you an answer. It would be better if you could delimit which part of your code is faulty and present only that.

Answer (score 1):

use a constructor for Executive class. Add

```
Executive(MainActivity activity){

m = activity;

}
```

Use MainActivity.java:25

```
public Executive exec = new Executive(this);
```

use Executive.java:21

```
MainActivity m =null;
```

Comment: Interesting! Didn't work however, returns a nullpointerexception at the first reference of m.

Comment: maybe some other problem in your code.  Move new Executive(this);  to oncreate of activity. Keep updating the code as and when you change ti